# Output validation error: Root element is missing, when mapping from Edifact D96A INVOIC to CDM

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

I've copied an XSLT map from another solution and are trying to modify it to the current solution. When I test the map using a standard D96 INVOIC test file I get an error saying that the root element is missing.

When I try to debug, the execution stops right after the first template, so something is not being matched correctly.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:EFACT_D96A_INVOIC" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/s0:EFACT_D96A_INVOIC">
    <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="userCSharp:StringUpperCase(&quot;1&quot;)" />
    <ns0:Cdm_PurchaseInvoice>
```

I have in my header the namespace prefix declared:

```
xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/EDIFACT/2006"
```

What could be the cause of this? The template should match, but it is not being applied.

Comment: Can you add the root node (including namespace) here?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by changing the declared namespace to the correct one specified by validating the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the declared namespace to the correct one specified by validating the map